# Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL - when running background script in new chrome tab using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to insert a console.log using background script in the current active tab.
This is working properly for all tabs except new chrome tab.

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL**
even after adding "chrome://" in host_permissions in manifest file of version - 3

Answer (score 1):

You can't; Chrome extensions are not allowed to access or run on `chrome://` urls or the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) for both security reasons and to prevent the alteration of the extensions management pages.